# Problems with Swipe Gesture in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, landscape

I have been trying to figure out a way to fix this on my own, without any luck.

Programming Language is Objective-C and SpriteKit is the technology.

I'm trying to make an `SKNode` move around the screen using swipe gestures. (In a landscape mode app)

The problem is when I swipe left or any other sides, the node will move the opposite direction and use another method than it's supposed to. It looks like the iPhone thinks it is in portrait mode. What should I do?

Here's the code:

Inside .h Declaring the node

```
SKNode *Main_Character;
```

Inside .m

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                    initWithTarget:self
                                                    action:@selector(SwipedLeft)] ;
    [oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                     initWithTarget:self
                                                     action:@selector(SwipedRight)] ;
    [oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeRight];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                  initWithTarget:self
                                                  action:@selector(SwipedUp)] ;
    [oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeUp];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                    initWithTarget:self
                                                    action:@selector(SwipedDown)] ;
    [oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeDown];
}

// Methods to make the node move when a swipe is called.
-(void)SwipedDown{
    SKAction *Move = [SKAction moveByX:0.00 y:-50 duration:2];

    [Main_Character runAction:Move];
}

-(void)SwipedUp{
    SKAction *Move = [SKAction moveByX:0.00 y:+50 duration:2];

    [Main_Character runAction:Move];
}

-(void)SwipedRight{
    SKAction *Move = [SKAction moveByX:+50 y:0.00 duration:2];

    [Main_Character runAction:Move];
}

-(void)SwipedLeft{
    SKAction *Move = [SKAction moveByX:-50 y:0.00 duration:2];

    [Main_Character runAction:Move];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your copy/paste have failed you, you need to fix your setDirections, you only set left, when you want to set other directions.

Comment: Copy Paste? Dont know what you mean.. But the code is written by me. And also, how do you fix "setDirections"?

Comment: you copy/pasted your code 4 times to handle the 4 directions: E.G. `[oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];` should be `[oneFingerSwipeUp setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];`

Comment: Stupid me.. Feels so stupid not have noticed that yet.. Thank you so much sir!